# Image randomization in qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm creating a qualtrics survey and I'd like to create a way to randomize which images participants will see on a given questions

Here's the basic code I have so far

```
var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
var picture = document.getElementById('picture');

banner.style.display = 'none';
picture.style.display = 'none';

images = [banner, picture];

function randomImage() {
    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random(0, images.length - 1) * 10);

    return images[idx];
};

var image1 = randomImage(); 
image1.style.display = 'block';
```

Where 'picture' and 'banner' are the ids of two images. However, this doesn't seem to work, the images disappear but a random image does not reappear. Any advice on a better way to make this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be...

```
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
```

... as at the moment you for some reason multiply the result by 10, having quite a low chance for the final result to be either 0 or 1.

Note that [**Math.random()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) doesn't take any arguments: it always generates a number in `[0, 1)` range.

Comment: Dang, this has been bugging me all day now. Thank you! works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) does not take any parameters, and returns a number between 0 and 1.  Instead, use the following formula:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_PLUS_ONE);
```

Where `MAX_PLUS_ONE` is one more than the maximum number you want generated.  In your case:

```
var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
```

`images.length` works here because the last index (largest number `idx` will be) will be one less than `images.length`